# Polynomial Deterministic Algorithm for MAX-QP problem with multiplicative errror $1/n$

Tags: graphs, quadratic-programming

**MAX-QP** problem (quadratic programming on boolean cube) statement:

> Given symmetrical matrix $A$ with 0 on diagonal
> $$A = (a_{ij}) : A^T = A, a_{ii} = 0$$
> Find maximum $x^TAx$ where $x \in \{0, 1\}^n$, in other words
> $$\max \sum_{ij}a_{ij}x_ix_j$$

Note that this problem is similar to the max-cut ploblem with no limitations of edge weights.

I want to find the deterministic polynomial time algorithm with multiplicative error $1/n$.

The only algoritm I know for this problem is probabilstic average algorith with multiplicative error $1/n$? But is there any way to derandomize it? The idea of this algorithm is the following: take random matching $\pi = \{(i_1, i_2), \dots, (i_{n-1}, i_n)\}$ and for every pair $(i, j)$ take $x_i$ random from $\{-1, 1\}$ and define $x_j$ such that $|a_{ij}| = a_{ij}x_ix_j$. So
$$\mathbb{E}[x^TAx] = \mathbb{E}[w(\pi)] = \frac{1}{n - 1}\sum_{ij}|a_{ij}|$$
So we have error $1/n$ only for graphs, where all weights nonnegative and equal.

Comment: Are you familiar with the method of conditional expectations?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus not sure, something like  this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_conditional_probabilities ? Can you explain your idea a bit? Should I derandomize the probabilistic average algorithm?

Comment: That's the first thing I would try.